# reindex command not working

Tags: reindex, ssl, command

I am trying to **reindex** using the following command from `public_html` folder **(root directory)**:

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

I have even tried

> bin/magento indexer:reindex

I receive the following message:

> Magento supports PHP 5.0 or later ...

Another error message:

> -bash: bin/magento: Permission Denied.

I am not a programmer. Could someone kindly explain in simple words how to solve this. Many thanks!

Comment: What is your PHP version? Enter the command `php -v` to get this.

Comment: Try sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: First upgrade your php version higher than your latest magento version.

Answer (score 0):

It seems permission issue on bin/magento folder.  To fix this issue, execute below command to add permission for the bin/magento.

```
chmod u+x bin/magento
```